# How do I pass data from viewController to swiftUI view?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, viewcontroller, arkit

I am working on an app that uses ARkit to detect images. When an image within the asset folder is detected, the app displays a swiftUI view on top of the image, and when an image is no longer tracked, the swiftUI view disappears. Up until here it all works fine.

Within the viewdidload method in the viewController file I am downloading and parsing a csv file from the internet. This also works.

Where I am struggling is to figure out how to pass the data parsed from the csv file that is within viewdidload to the swiftUI view, so that I can work with these data on the swiftUI view that I am creating. For example, I will show specific data depending on which image is detected.

I found other stackoverflow questions where they discuss how to pass data between viewcontrollers, but not between a viewcontroller and a swiftUI view.

Below is my code.

Here is my ViewController.swift file

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit
import SwiftUI

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        // load csv file from dropbox
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/0d0cr5o9rfxzrva/test.csv?dl=1")!
        let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { location, response, error in
            guard let location = location else { return }
            do {
                // get path to directory
                let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
                print(documentDirectory.path)
                // giving name to file
                let name = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.suggestedFilename ?? location.lastPathComponent
                //create a destination url
                let destination = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(name)
                // check if file already exist
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destination.path) {
                    //remove the file
                   try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destination)
                }
                // move file from old to new url
                try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: location, to: destination)
                // reading the file
                let data = try String(contentsOf: destination, encoding: .utf8)
                
                //parsed csv
                let datos = self.csv(data: data)
                print(datos)
                
            } catch {
                print("ERROR", error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        
    }
    

    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARImageTrackingConfiguration()

        guard let trackingImages = ARReferenceImage.referenceImages(inGroupNamed: "AR Resources", bundle: nil) else {
        
            fatalError("Couldn't load tracking images")
            
            }
           
            configuration.trackingImages = trackingImages
            
        configuration.maximumNumberOfTrackedImages = 2
        
        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)
    }
        
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }

    // MARK: - ARSCNViewDelegate
    

    // Override to create and configure nodes for anchors added to the view's session.
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
        
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else {return nil}
        
        
        let plane = SCNPlane(width: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width,
                         height: imageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height)
        
    
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
        
        planeNode.eulerAngles.x = -.pi / 2
        
        
        if let imageName = imageAnchor.referenceImage.name {
            imageController(for: planeNode, imageName: imageName)
            
        }
    
        
        let node = SCNNode()
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
        return node
            
        }

   


    func imageController(for node: SCNNode, imageName: String) {
    
    
        let imgView = UIHostingController(rootView: imageView(imageName: imageName))
    
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imgView.willMove(toParent: self)
        
        self.addChild(imgView)
        
        imgView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500)
        
        self.view.addSubview(imgView.view)
        
        self.showImageView(hostingVC: imgView, on: node)
        
    }
    
    }

    

func showImageView(hostingVC: UIHostingController<imageView>, on node: SCNNode) {
        
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        
        hostingVC.view.isOpaque = false
        material.diffuse.contents = hostingVC.view
        node.geometry?.materials = [material]
        
        hostingVC.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        
    }

    
// parsing csv method
    func csv(data: String) -> [[String]] {
        var result: [[String]] = []
        let rows = data.components(separatedBy: "\n")
        for row in rows {
            let columns = row.components(separatedBy: ",")
            result.append(columns)
            
        }
        return result
    }
    
   
}
```

and here is my swiftUI view file

```
import SwiftUI

struct imageView: View {

    var imageName: String

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack{
        Color.white
            Text("hello \(imageName)")
            
        }
            
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can try to make use of NotificationCenter or Combine Publishers in order to pass the data

Comment: You're already passing data between the controllers with `imageName`.  Just add another `var` of the type you want to send to your `imageView`, add the same `var` and type to your `ViewController`.  When you download csv, instead of creating a variable with `let davos`, set the property you just added on your controller and then send that `var` to your `imageView` the same way you are sending `imageName`.

Comment: thanks @clawesome. I thought so because I can pass imageName. However when I try to do the same with `datos` I get 'use of unresolved identifier'. I am clearly missing something. Would you be able to show on my code? Thank you.

Comment: What class type is `datos`?

Comment: It’s a multi-dimensional array [[String]]

Comment: You need to make `datos` a property of the VC -- it's a local variable inside a closure right now. Then, it will be available to pass when you construct the view

Comment: @LouFranco could you explain how to do that using my example? I keep getting `use of unresolved identifier` when I try to do that. I am adding data: [[String]] to the VC but obviously missing something. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `datos` to be passed to the constructor of the View, but the only `datos` you have in your code is a local variable in a closure.

You need to make a new property in the VC

`var datos: [[String]]?`

Then, when you get the data, save it in this property

`self.datos = ....`

Then, when you construct the View, pass `self.datos`

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I was also missing passing datos to the imageController method